# 403 error trying to access file on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, http-status-code-403

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server at `http://images.example.com` with this in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/richblockspoorblocks.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias images.example.com
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        DocumentRoot /home/username/var/www/example.com/public_html
        ErrorLog /home/username/var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/username/var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a file `/home/username/var/www/example.com/public_html/test.txt`.

But when I navigate my browser to `http://images.example.com/test.txt`, I get a 403 forbidden error.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /test.txt on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at images.example.com Port 80
```

Here's what I see when I run `ls -la` while in `~/`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data username 4096 May 20 21:32 var
```

`error.log` only has a `client denied by server configuration` message.

I've already run `apache2 restart`.

What must I change to see `test.txt` in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be placing your website files and **DocumentRoot** in a `/home/user` sub-directory:

```
    DocumentRoot /home/username/var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Usually, Apache works in `/var/www`, you might have a mistake nesting like that in your user's home directory. If you upload and point the **DocumentRoot** somewhere else than the default location (`/var/www/`), you might need to fix the owner/group/others and their permissions, so the user or group (`www-data`) for apache can read them.

Is there any reason to be using your user's home for the webserver DocumentRoot?

If you really want it there, you might try to change the group, to allow apache to read it:

**I don't recommend this, unless you know what you are doing**

`chgrp -R www-data /home/username/var/www/example.com/public_html`

That should probably make it work. Although you might also have to change some permissions, depending how you copied/uploaded the files to that directory.

ps. Again, unless there is some really good reason for that directory structure, I would go for the default `/var/www`.

Comment: I put everything in `/home/user` because the partition it's mounted on has a lot of inodes, which I need. Also, I'll update my question with ownership info. I haven't run any code you've recommended yet.

Comment: I ran `chgrp -R www-data /home/username/var/www/example.com/public_html` and `apache restart`. But I still get the 403 error trying to open the file in my browser.

Comment: I ended up moving everything to `/var/www` after reinstalling the Ubuntu setup on one partition. Lots of Inodes